# Laravel Livewire V3 scope model to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm building a web application in Laravel 11 using Livewire v3. I have a `Setting` model. I'm using Livewire components for my pages, a `Setting` has a `user_id` column and I want to make sure *(along with bindings)* that the setting a user is trying to load belongs to the user.

Is there a clean way to do this with my routes file? I have a form class abstraction which contains a `setSetting` method, except this doesn't check that the setting actually belongs to the user.

Here's my `web.php` file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Livewire\Pages\Settings\SettingIndex;
use App\Livewire\Pages\Settings\SettingCreate;
use App\Livewire\Pages\Settings\SettingUpdate;

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->prefix('settings')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', SettingIndex::class)->name('settings.index');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'create', SettingCreate::class)->name('settings.create');
    Route::match(['get', 'patch'], '{setting}/edit', SettingUpdate::class)->name('settings.edit');
});
```

My `SettingUpdate` class which returns the view:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Pages\Settings;

use App\Livewire\Forms\SettingForm;
use App\Models\Setting;
use Livewire\Attributes\Rule;
use Livewire\Component;

class SettingUpdate extends Component
{
    public SettingForm $form;

    public Setting $setting;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->form->setSetting($this->setting);
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $this->setting);

        $this->form->validate();

        $this->form->update();

        $this->dispatch('setting.' . $this->setting->id . '.updated');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pages.settings.setting-update');
    }
}
```

I'm using: `$this->authorize('update', $this->setting);` for checking the update, should I do this for the `setSetting`? Or is there an alternative way beyond policies.